# When I run this code I get this error; Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid

Tags: vb.net, string, integer

It highlights the section surrounded by **#####** to be in correct but I don't see the error.

```
Private Sub UIDeposit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles UIDeposit.Click
    'Declear(NumberOfCoins)

    Dim depositCash(7) As Integer

    'coins as expessions 
    depositCash(COIN1P) = CInt(UIPence1.Text)
    depositCash(COIN2P) = CInt(UIPence2.Text)
    depositCash(COIN5P) = CInt(UIPence5.Text)
    depositCash(COIN10P) = CInt(UIPence10.Text)
    depositCash(COIN20P) = CInt(UIPence20.Text)
    depositCash(COIN50P) = CInt(UIPence50.Text)
    depositCash(COIN100P) = CInt(UIPound1.Text)
    **depositCash(COIN200P) = CInt(UIPound2.Text)**

    'Displays 
    SetCoinAmount("0")
    depositAmount(depositCash)
    DisplaySandingAmount()

    'Curser Should Focus
    UIPence1.Focus()
End Sub
```

Comment: Please add the appropriate language tag.

Comment: if the textbox is empty ("") it cant convert to a number.  Use Integer.TryParse instead or test for empty textbox.text before using CINT.

Comment: There is maybe a Textbox empty. In your method you must manage the case where a Textbox is empty.

Comment: What part of the error message didn't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

If you assign a string value to an integer, that string must be converted to an integer before it is assigned. If the string does not contain a number, then it causes an error. You can test the string with an if statement using the isnumeric or integer.tryparse function to make sure it is a legitimate number before you assign the string (the value from the textbox) to the integer (depositCash).